# Doubt about the definition of $G$-coinvariant

Tags: group-cohomology, group-rings

I am learning some group cohomology from Romyar Sharifi's [online notes](http://math.ucla.edu/~sharifi/groupcoh.pdf). (Everything I have written here can be found on page 5-6)

Let $G$ be a finite multiplicative group. Consider the group ring $\mathbb{Z}[G]$. The augmentation ideal is defined as follows:

Consider the ring homomorphism $\epsilon:\mathbb{Z}[G]\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$
$$\epsilon:\sum_{g\in G}a_gg\mapsto\sum_{g\in G}a_g$$

> > The augmentation ideal is the kernel of $\epsilon$.

$\text{}$
An abelian group $A$ (written additively) is called a $G$-module if there is an action of $G$ on $A$ such that

(1) $1\cdot a=a$ for all $a\in A$.

(2) $g\cdot (a+b)=g\cdot a+g\cdot b$ for all $g\in G$ and $a,b\in A$.

(3) $g\cdot(h\cdot a)=(gh)\cdot a$ for all $g,h\in G$ and $a\in A$

The action of $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ on $A$ is defined as 
$$(\sum_{g\in G}a_gg)\cdot a=\sum_{g\in G}a_g(g\cdot a)$$

The group of $G$-coinvariants is defined as

> > $$A_G=\frac{G}{I_GA}$$

$\text{}$
I have doubt about the definition of $I_GA$. Is it defined like this:
$$I_GA=\{\sum_{g\in G}(g\cdot a_g-a_g) | a_g\in A \}$$

I have one more doubt: It is mentioned that $A_G$ is the largest quotient of $A$ fixed by $G$. Does $G$ act on $A/I_GA$ (if so, how is the action defined)?

Comment: Yes, $G$ acts on the quotient since it acts on $A$ and $I_GA$ is a $G$-submodule.

Comment: For $I_GA$ to be a submodule, we must have $g\cdot (I_GA)\subseteq I_GA$ for all $g\in G$. But I can't understand how that is happening.

Comment: Is my definition of $I_GA$ correct ?

Comment: Yes, your definition is correct, and it should be fairly straightforward to show that it is invariant under the action of $G$.

Comment: Let $h\in G$ be arbitrary. 
Then $h\cdot(\sum_{g\in G}[ga_g-a_g])=\sum_{g\in G} [(hg)\cdot a_g-h\cdot a_g]$. What after this ? If $G$ is abelian, then the proof is done. If not, then how to proceed?

Comment: @random_guy Note that $(hg)\cdot a_g - h \cdot a_g = (hgh^{-1})\cdot (h\cdot a_g) - h \cdot a_g$, $hgh^{-1} \in G$ and $h \cdot a_g \in A$

Comment: @random_guy, there is a typo, the $G$-coinvariants is $A_G=A/I_GA$  not $A_G=G/I_GA$.